# how to send variable with onclick to javascript file

Tags: php, jquery, html

Iam trying to make some queries from database and trying to make filter from a map according to the country.

ive written the java script code and it works normaly and query php file as well. 
my problem just how to send a name with onclick function to start the query. 
the shown problem is always that the query variable is empty. 
the code as following :

```
<map name="Map" id="Map">
<area shape="poly" coords="948,4,454,927,452,932,454" value="USA" onclick="getCountry(this.value)" />
```

and javascript code which works fine:

```
function getCountry(value){

  $.post("search.php"
    , 
    {query:value},
    function(data) {
         $('#results').html(data);
      });

}
```

the variable query in search.php comes always back with error that it didnt recieved any data.

thank you in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` is not a valid property for the `area` element so you can't use that. You could try `title` instead, which is a [global attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes) available to all HTML elements.

```js
function bar(d){
  alert(d);
}
```

```html
<div style='width: 50px; height: 50px; background: red;' title='FOO' onclick='bar(this.title)'></div>
```

Comment: you mean make the map picture in the div which will forward the value inside the area ?

Comment: i have to make more than one onclick function because it is a world map.

Comment: No, I mean use `title` on your `area` elements to hold the value instead of `value`. The `div` here was only for example. Or you could simply use data-* attributes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*